# obj: any in forEach loop (how to avoid implicit any)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following code:

```
(object as any).children.forEach( obj => { });
```

I've set (object as any) beacuse children is private, and so I cannot access it without the 'any'. I want it private, I access it here because it's on muy unit tests.

But I get the following error on the obj `Parameter 'obj' implicitly has an 'any' type`. which is not allowed with my compilation options.

How can I set the type of obj? I know what type it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the type of obj? I know what type it is.

Just declare it. For instance, if the type is `Foo`:

```
(object as any).children.forEach( (obj: Foo) => { });
// -------------------------------^---^^^^^^
```

But:

> I've set (object as any) beacuse children is private, and so I cannot access it without the 'any'

That suggests you should either

1. Not access it, or
2. Make it public if accessing it where you're accessing it should be allowed

...rather than working around it with `as any`.

Comment: Thansk T.J. I want it to be private, I access it from un unit tests just for testing purposes. Declaring it as (obj: Foo) solves the problem